# Unable to get single user data from list - REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, ejs

> routes
>
> > user.js
>
> view
>
> > layout.ejs
> >
> > user.ejs
> >
> > users.ejs
>
> app.js

REST API - "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2"

I have two GET request. 
Users.ejs renders three dynamic buttons with an href, also dynamic.
User.ejs renders a single user.

I'm passing user id to users.ejs so that when the user clicks on that button,
it will render user.ejs and the link will be for eg- 127.0.0.1:8080/1,
127.0.0.1:8080/2, 127.0.0.1:8080/3.

But whenever I click any of the button, the url becomes "http://127.0.0.1:8080/%20+".

user.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const request = require("request");

global.url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";

router.get("/users", (req, res) => {
request.get(url, function(err, resp, body) {
 const parse = JSON.parse(body);

res.render("users", {
    obj : parse
    });
  });
});

router.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
request.get(url, (err, resp, body) => {
const obj = JSON.parse(body);
global.user = obj.data[req.params.id];

console.log('USER:', user);

res.render('user', { 
    user
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

users.ejs

```
<% obj.data.forEach(function(o) { %>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">
<a href="/ + <%= JSON.stringify(user) %> "> 
    <%= o["first_name"] %> 
</a>
</button>
<% }); %>
```

user.ejs

```
<h1><%= JSON.stringify(user) %></h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you need to use index inside forEach loop:

```
<% obj.data.forEach(function(o, index) { %>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">
<a href="/<%= index %> "> 
    <%= o["first_name"] %> 
</a>
</button>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: Hi, The url will be /4 , /5 , /6. I want to access obj.data[0] , obj.data[1], obj.data[2]. So, the url must be 127.0.0.:8080/0 , 127.0.0.:8080/1, 127.0.0.:8080/2. How to achieve this?

Comment: In this case you need to use `index` inside `forEach` loop:
`<% obj.data.forEach(function(o, index) { %>`
And the index will be 0, 1, 2 ...
So you can use it like:
<a href="/<%= index %>">

Comment: @SharzilShaikh I think the url `127.0.0.1:8080/users/1` will be fine (REST style), just change `router.get("/:id"` to `router.get("/users/:id"` then click to a url.

Comment: @Eugene Hey Thanks! Please edit your answer so that I can accept it. :)